# Setting rwx default permissions for the group, but just rw default permissions for files

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, defaults

I have a collection of directories that should have permissions `rw-rw-r--` for all contained regular files, and `rwxrwxr-x` for all contained directories. I can set the default permissions for all regular files and directories with something like `setfacl -R -d -m g::rw /directory/name`, but this will set the default permissions for new files and new directories to the same value, which I don't want.

How can I create a chunk of the filesystem with `rwx` default permissions for the group, but just `rw` default permissions for files?

Answer (score 4):

If you set the `x` flag for everything then the user "create" permissions, will also take effect. which means that typically files won't have the `x` flag:

```
$ setfacl -d -m u::rwx .
$ setfacl -d -m g::rwx .
$ setfacl -d -m o::rx . 
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: sweh
# group: sweh
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x

$ mkdir DIR
$ ls -ld DIR
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 sweh sweh 4096 Aug 10 20:05 DIR
$ touch file
$ ls -l file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 10 20:05 file
$ touch DIR/file
$ ls -l DIR/file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 10 20:06 DIR/file
```

This survives umask changes:

```
$ umask 077
$ mkdir DIR2
$ ls -ld DIR2
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 sweh sweh 4096 Aug 10 20:08 DIR2
$ touch file3
$ ls -l file3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 10 20:08 file3
$ > file4
$ ls -l file4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 10 20:08 file4
```

The newly created directories inherit the default ACL:

```
$ getfacl DIR2
# file: DIR2
# owner: sweh
# group: sweh
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

This won't remove the `x` flag from compiled programs, though:

```
$ gcc -o x x.c
$ ls -l x
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sweh sweh 6680 Aug 10 20:12 x
```

In this case that's because `gcc` does a `chmod` and so overrides the default:

```
open("x", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
....
chmod("x", 0775)
```